# How to add a particular value to a particular position in rows of a specific column?

Tags: r, string, format, row

How to add a particular value to a particular position in rows of a specific column? I have this column called ID:

```
ID
subject01_1
subject01_2
subject01_3
...
```

I need to add a zero after the underline for all the subjects:

```
ID
subject01_01
subject01_02
subject01_03
subject01_04
...
```

Comment: And how to extract only rows that end in "_02" and "_03" in another dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to add a `0` after the `_` with `gsub`:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "ID
subject01_1
subject01_2
subject01_3", header = TRUE)

df$ID <- gsub("\\_(\\d+)", "\\_0\\1", df$ID)
df
#>             ID
#> 1 subject01_01
#> 2 subject01_02
#> 3 subject01_03
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Using `sprintf`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(ID = str_replace(ID, "\\d+$",
        function(x) sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(x))))
```

-output

```
   ID
1 subject01_01
2 subject01_02
3 subject01_03
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("subject01_1", "subject01_2", "subject01_3"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```